# issue with sed printing a specific line

Tags: sed

I have below data in which i am interested to find the lines with START keyword and match process2 also, then to get only the 4th line from process 2. I developed the below sed code, but it prints all lines from process2 to process6.
Can you please help me in printing the 4th line only.

```
sed -n -e '/START/{p};/process2/{N;N;N;N;p};d' data.txt

START1
process1:  data11345
process2:  data12235
process3:  data13123
process4:  data13123
process5:  data13123
process6:  data13123

START2
process1:  data213345
process2:  data225555
process3:  data235677
process4:  data13123
process5:  data13123
process6:  data13123

START3
process1:  data314332
process2:  data322222
process3:  data335556
process4:  data13123
process5:  data13123
process6:  data13123
process7:  data13123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To output fourth line after `process2`:

```
sed -n -e '/START/,/^$/{//p;/process2/{n;n;n;n;p}}' file
```

**Explanation:**

Within blocks between `START` and `^$`(next blank line or end of file):

- `//p`: print lines matching the address range
- if `/process2/` is found,`n;n;n;n`
- adds fourth line from it to the pattern space and print it.

Comment: Thanks SLePort, this is working real well. Just one minor thing i need is to print the START string as well. I tried to modify the command as below, but it doesn't work.                                                                                            
                                                                                                               
     `sed -n -e '/START/{n,p},/^$/{/process2/{n;n;n;n;p}}' data.txt`

Comment: You can add `//p` to print lines matching the address range. I edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working great!